# How to get fields (attributes) out of a single CoreData record without using [index]?

Tags: core-data, xcode7, magicalrecord-2.2

I have one CoreData record that contains all of the app's settings.  When I read that single record (using MagicalRecord), I get an array back.  My question is:  can I get addressabiltiy to the individual fields in the record without using "[0]" (field index), but rather using [@"shopOpens"]?

I was thinking something like this, but I don't think it's right:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"aMostRecentFlag == 1"];  //  find old records
preferenceData = [PreferenceData MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate inContext:defaultContext];  //  source

   NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableDictionary *preferencesDict = [[userDefaults dictionaryForKey:@"preferencesDictionary"] mutableCopy];  //  target

//  start filling the userDefaults from the last Preferences record
/*
 Printing description of preferencesDict: {
 apptInterval = 15;
 colorScheme = Saori;
 servicesType = 1;
 shopCloses = 2000;
 shopOpens = 900;
 showServices = 0;
 syncToiCloud = 0;
 timeFormat = 12;
 }
 */

[preferencesDict setObject: preferenceData.colorScheme  forKey:@"shopOpens"];
```

**UPDATE**

This is how I finally figured it out, for those who have a similar question:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"aMostRecentFlag == 0"];  //  find old records
NSFetchRequest *freqest = [PreferenceData MR_requestAllWithPredicate: filter];
[freqest setResultType: NSDictionaryResultType];
NSDictionary *perferenceData = [PreferenceData MR_executeFetchRequest:freqest];
```

Comment: Why are you using both Magical Record and NSUserDefaults to store the same information? It looks like NSUserDefaults will suffice.

Comment: Need CoreData store because it will eventually go to iCloud for sharing.  Preferences is one of 3 entities, and the only one that needs to be changed for the eventual store in iCloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I've never used magical record, so the very first part is just an educated guess.

I imagine that preferenceData is an instance of `NSArray` firstly because the method name uses `findAll` which indicates that it will return multiple instances.  Secondly, a normal core data fetch returns an array, and there is no obvious reason for that find method to return anything different.  Thirdly, you referenced using an index operation in your question.

So, `preferenceData` is most likely an array of all objects in the store that match the specified predicate.  You indicated that there is only one such object, which means you can just grab the first one.

```
PreferenceData *preferenceData = [[PreferenceData
    MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate inContext:defaultContext] firstObject];
```

Now, unless it is nil, you have the object from the core data store.

You should be able to reference it in any way you like to access its attributes.

Note, however, that you can fetch objects from core data as dictionary using `NSDictionaryResultType`, which may be a better alternative for you.

Also, you can send `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:` to a managed object to get a dictionary of specific attributes.

Comment: MagicalRecord really has nothing to do with the question, and I don't know why I put it in there!  That said, yes, I know CoreData returns an array; I want to take that array (there will probably be only 1 record returned that is pertinent due to the *mostRecentFlag*).  I want to take that record and retrieve each field (attribute) and place it in a *managedObject* which has about 50 fields in it.  I know I can do it using a numerical index, but I was hoping to use the field names from the *managedObject* to avoid CoreData changing the order of the attributes in the CoreData record.

Comment: Please read the second part of the post.  You can return fetched objects as dictionaries.  You can also create a dictionary out of a managed object and a set of keys.  You can go even further and set values from a dictionary `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`.  The cocoa API provides a decent dynamic interface for changing and observing object based on key value pairs.

Comment: I figured it out with your help... thanks... I have updated the question to show my version of how to do it.